# oracle: format a number with slash

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column like this:

```
Productnr
1
25
260
3700
51126
```

and I should write a query to display the column like this:

```
productnr
0/01
0/25
2/60
37/00
511/26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```sql
SELECT
    Productnr,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        SUBSTR('000' || Productnr,
               -GREATEST(3, LENGTH(Productnr)),
               GREATEST(3, LENGTH(Productnr))),
        '(..)$',
        '/\1'
    ) AS Productnr_out
FROM yourTable;
```

This approach first left pads the input with zeroes to a length of 3.  Then, it inserts a forward slash before the final two characters using a regex replacement.

Comment: I tried with "5515" and the output ist false: 5/51

Comment: I tried with your new code. tried with "1" and the output is false: 1

Comment: @Rezu I'm on a cell phone and it is very hard to test.  Reload your page; the latest edit seems to get it right for all inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `to_char()` and some string and arithmetic operations:

```
replace(to_char(Productnr / 100, 'FM99990.00'), '.', '/')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e63a2a269065283a5d4d7c67aee5139) is a db<>fiddle.